# laravel php7 debian 7.5 site deployment has illegal chareters, dont know why

Tags: php, laravel, debian

i have deployed a laravel site on debian 7.5, apache2, php7. in my mac the site is fine, but after deployed, site reports following error:the php files all are utf-8 code, and the php.ini shows the php7's default chareter set is utf-8 as well, pls help me out there, thanks in advance.

ErrorException in Mbstring.php line 351:
iconv_strpos(): Detected an illegal character in input string

in Mbstring.php line 351
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'iconv_strpos(): Detected an illegal character in input string', '/var/www/stockhit/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php', '351', array('haystack' => '��J��`�I�3���؉�W� �"�l���', 'needle' => 'base64:', 'offset' => '0', 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'))

Comment: One way to solve this would be to use `mb_strpos()` instead. The above generally occurs when the input and output charset are set to the same and an illegal character is passed in the input. Can you post your usage of `iconv_strpos()` ?

Comment: i do not use it, but laravel 5's vendor does,    from below report illegal charet  :at EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher('��J��`�I�3���؉�W� �"�l���', 'AES-256-CBC') in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 25

Comment: Go to artisan CLI on your debian server and do `key:generate` to get a new app key.

Comment: i have tried key:generate to use new key, dont work,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally got it down, somehow, indebian, the key generate will generate a string start with: Base64:........ , and the 'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC', it doesnt allow this this format, the solution is manually cut base64andsomechar, remain 32 length string, then the problem solve~

Answer (score 3):

Alextre's solution (while I'm unsure of its security ramifications) did in fact work for me too.  I removed the "base64:" from the beginning of the APP_KEY setting in my .env file, and then trimmed the remaining key to 32 characters (by simply deleting them from the end of the row).

My setup is Ubuntu 16.04LTS Xenial with Nginx and PHP 7.

Comment: This solution worked for me too.. but wth did this happen all of a sudden out of the blue? My site was working fine a few days ago.. and then all of a sudden after composer update it starts doing this? wth... this kind of stuff is nasty!